# FireFox geckodriver Not callable in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

Hello i try to use FireFox geckodriver in python by Selenium Exactly like this :

```
driver = webdriver.firefox()
siteAddress='https://stackoverflow.com'
driver.get(siteAddress)
```

But i get this error:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

Also my WebDriver is near of My Py App :

[Location Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDVid.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webdriver.firefox` is *module* while you need to use `webdriver.Firefox` *class instance*

Try to replace

```
driver = webdriver.firefox()
```

with

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```